# Create data frame from many files which has more than N line of content

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to create a data frame from many files in a directory and have managed to do that, luckily. I have used the following code to read the file contents into the data frame, which has two columns: "Title" and "Lyrics", where the "Lyrics" column contains the content of the file and the "Title" column is the filename.

```
file_temp = [os.path.join(data_folder,i) for i in os.listdir(data_folder) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(data_folder,i))]

df = pd.DataFrame()

#for every file in folder, read it and append to a empty dataframe with column filename as 'Title'
for file in file_temp:
    _df = pd.read_csv(file, names =['lyrics'], header=None, index_col=False, sep='\n', encoding='utf-8')
    _df['Title'] = os.path.split(file)[-1]
    df = df.append(_df)
df_group = df.groupby('Title').agg({'lyrics': lambda x: " ".join(x)}).reset_index()
```

What I need to get is, the data frame should only contain the contents of the files with more than N lines. For example, below is the first file which has the following contents

```
       आज न छोड़ेंगे बस हमजोली
       
       खेलेंगे हम होली
       
       चाहे भीगे तेरी चुनरिया
       
       चाहे भीगे रे चोली
       
       खेलेंगे हम होली
       
       होली है!
```

And the second file with contents

```
           ए पार्टी ओ पार्टी
       
       ए पार्टी पार्टी पार्टी
```

Would it be possible to only read the files into the data frame which has more than 2 line of contents in it? Which would mean, the second file should not be read into the data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to know number of lines in a file unless you read it. If there's a large number of files you need to process though I would recommend using a function su h as the below to get the number of lines in a file:

```
def lines_in_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        return len(lines)
```

You can then use this function in an if statement like this:

```
for file in temp_file:
    if lines_in_file(file) > n:
        pd.read_csv(file)
        .... The rest of your code
```

Reason for this approach is that pandas read_csv is pretty slow compared to the approach used in this function.
If you rather stick with pandas to do all the reading of files you could use `_df.shape[0]` to get the number of lines in the dataframe and have something like this:

```
if _df.shape[0] > n:
    df = df.append(_df)
```